# Underscore.js filter not returning all results

Tags: javascript, regex, underscore.js

I am trying to build an filtering function that works similar to the way an auto-complete field would work. I am using Underscore.js to filter an array of names. Here is a JSFiddle that demonstrates the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/PWcVM/

And for those who would rather not jump to JSFiddle, here is the example in plain text.

HTML:

```
<p>Type the name 'Craig' into the text field</p>
<input class="query" type="text" />
<p>There are 4 Craig's in the data array. The results below should output those 4 Craigs. For some reason, it only outputs two.</p>
<p>Results:</p>
<textarea class="results" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```
var data = ["Aaron Abram", "Abbie Hanson", "Abraham Vázquez", "Ace Marrero", "Adam D. Chaitin", "Adam Duzey", "Adam Reichental", "Adam Scott", "Adam Smythe", "Addison McCaleb", "Ahmad Childress", "Aidas Petrulis", "Aldo Nievas", "Alex Alexapolsky", "Alexander R. Lampone", "Alexandra Elizabeth London", "Alexandra Jacobs", "Alexis Jones", "Allan Louis", "Allie Tintle", "Alyssa Wada", "Amanda Armstrong", "Amanda Olmstead", "Amber Fox", "Amber Graves", "Amy Berkin-Chavez", "Amy Buggy", "Amy Rush", "Amy Schlumberger", "Andi Dzilums", "Andre Savage", "Andrew Fryer", "Andrew Rivetty", "Angel Chavez", "Angel Lewis", "Angela Truong", "Anthony Wentzel", "Anya Estrov", "Aram Homampour", "Ariana Blumenfeld-James", "Armo Movsessian", "Ashley DeMeza", "Ashley Froschauer", "Athena Asklipiadis", "Athena Stamos", "Audryn Swigert", "Augie Sanchez", "Avi Horn", "Bali Ciri Yoman", "Bali Distinction Norman", "Barnaby Hitzig", "Betty Tran Chillino", "Bill McGovern", "Blues Bob", "Bob Cribbs", "Bob West", "Bobby DiGiacomo", "Borivoj Ivanovic", "Brad Horwitz", "Brad Ormand", "Bradley F. Cole", "Brandon Jordan", "Brandon Kosoko", "Brent Nelson", "Brett Vadset", "Brian Kubat", "Bridget Betts", "Brock Winberg", "Bryan C Dickson", "Caleb Bacon", "Carlos Carreras", "Carlos Castro", "Carlos Chávez", "Caryn Saxena", "Celina Chavanette", "Ceren Güven", "Chad Buechler", "Charles Winemiller", "Charlie Diaz", "Cheri Kingsley", "Chloe Sherman-Pepe", "Chris Hackett", "Chris Han", "Chris Laughter", "Chris Mabli", "Chris McGarry", "Chris Scott", "Chris Ueland", "Christelle Penalosa", "Christine Is Lovely", "Clark McCutchen", "Colleen Steckloff Mayo", "Cory J Thomas", "Craig Adams", "Craig Duro", "Craig Fredrics", "Craig Phelps", "Curt Bonnem", "Dalilah Rain", "Damien Nemire-Pepe"];

_.each(data, function (name) {
    $('textarea.results').val($('textarea.results').val() + name + "\n");
});

$('input.query').bind('input', function (event) {
    var pattern = new RegExp($(event.currentTarget).val(), 'gim'),
        filteredResults = _.filter(data, function (name) {
            return pattern.test(name)
        });

    $('textarea.results').val('');

    _.each(filteredResults, function (name) {
        $('textarea.results').val($('textarea.results').val() + name + "\n");
    });
});
```

I get some results back, just not ALL of the results that should be coming back.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could get rid of the global flag from RegExp this should work.

```
var pattern = new RegExp($(event.currentTarget).val(), 'im');
```

Comment: Indeed...I need a why before I can accept this answer. It does indeed fix it, but a little more background will make this answer complete.

Comment: @AdamDuro See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610251/why-pattern-testname-opposite-results-on-consecutive-calls) : using the `g` modifier turns the RegExp object into an iterator. There is no reason to use this modifier when using the `test` function.