# Why `pattern.test(name)` opposite results on consecutive calls

Tags: javascript, regex

Why is this code returning first true, then false

```
var pattern = new RegExp("mstea", 'gi'), name = "Amanda Olmstead";

console.log('1', pattern.test(name));
console.log('1', pattern.test(name));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zNkFv/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`g` is for repeating searches. It changes the regular expression object into an iterator. If you want to use the `test` function to check your string is valid according to your pattern, remove this modifier :

```
var pattern = new RegExp("mstea", 'i'), name = "Amanda Olmstead";
```

The `test` function, contrary to `replace` or `match` doesn't consume the whole iteration, which lets it in a "bad" state. You should probably never use this modifier when using the `test` function.

Comment: will it keep tract of the last found index across different `test()` calls

Comment: @ArunPJohny I don't think it can ever make sense to use the 'g' flag with the test function.

Comment: I came across this problem while I was debugging [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608747/underscore-js-filter-not-returning-all-results), probably  you can answer that too

Comment: @ArunPJohny This seems the same problem, yes. I let you answer it.

Comment: It is the same problem, because of the loops - only alternate results will be shown

Answer (score 7):

You don't want to use gi in combination with pattern.test. The g flag means that it keeps track of where you are running so it can be reused. So instead, you should use:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("mstea", 'i'), name = "Amanda Olmstead";

console.log('1', pattern.test(name));
console.log('1', pattern.test(name));
```

Also, you can use /.../[flags] syntax for regex, like so:

```
var pattern = /mstea/i;
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you set the `g` modifier.

Remove it for your case.

```
var pattern = new RegExp("mstea", 'i'), name = "Amanda Olmstead";
```

Answer (score 3):

**It isn't a bug.**

The `g` causes it to carry out the next attempted match for the **substring, after the first match.** And that is why it returns false in every even attempt.

```
First attempt: 
It is testing "Amanda Olmstead"

Second attempt:
It is testing "d" //match found in previous attempt (performs substring there)

Third attempt:
It is testing "Amanda Olmstead" again //no match found in previous attempt

... so on
```

MDN page for [`Regexp.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Description) states:

> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec
>   method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string.
>   When you do so, the search starts at the **substring** of str specified by
>   the regular expression's lastIndex property

MDN page for [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) states:

> As with exec (or in combination with it), test called multiple times
>   on the same **global** regular expression instance will advance past the
>   previous match.