# Javascript RegExp Producing Unusual Results with Global Modifer

Tags: javascript, regex

I was able to work around this issue as it turned out I didn't need /g. But I was wondering if anyone would be able to explain why the following behavior occurred.

```
x = RegExp( "w", "gi" )
x.test( "Women" )
    = true
x.test( "Women" )
    = false
```

It would continue to alternate between true and false when evaluating the expression. Which was an issue because I was using the same compiled RegExp on a list of strings, leading some to evaluate to false when they should have been true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `g` flag, the regex stores the end position of the match in its `lastIndex` property. The next time you call any of `test()`, `exec()`, or `match()`, the regex will start from that index in the string to try and find a match.

When no match is found, it will return null, and `lastIndex` is reset to 0. This is why your test kept alternating. It would match the `W`, and then `lastIndex` would be set to 1. The next time you called it, null would be returned, and `lastIndex` would be reset.

A pitfall related to this is when your regex can match the empty string. In that case, `lastIndex` will not change, and if you are getting all matches, there will be an infinite loop. In this case you should manually adjust `lastIndex` if it matched the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using global modifier in a regex used for `test`, because it preserves the index of the last search and starts the next test from there.

I'd asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610251/why-pattern-testname-opposite-results-on-consecutive-calls).

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

> As with exec (or in combination with it), test called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.

Essentially, the `RegExp` object `x` keeps track of its last match internally.  When you call `.test` again, it attempts to match starting after the `"w"`

Of course this is only true of a regex object instance.

```
> /w/gi.test('Women')
true
> /w/gi.test('Women')
true
```