# RegExp.match doesn't match on jQuery.attr result while it should

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just stumbled over this very strange behavior. I have a regex that extracts Youtube video IDs from embedded iframes. The regex looks like this:

```
var regex = /(?:youtu\.be|youtube\.com|ytimg\.com|youtube-nocookie\.com).*(?:\/|\?v=|\&v=|\?video_id=|\&video_id=)([\w\-_]{11})[^\w\-_]?/ig;
```

I now have an embedded Youtube iframe that looks like this:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="300" height="200"
  src="//www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=0&origin=//example.com"
  frameborder="0"/>
```

As you can see, that regex should match against the `src` attribute of this element. However, if I do the following code it will return `false`:

```
regex.test( $('#ytplayer').attr('src') );
```

You will say "Well, your regex is obviously wrong, check it again". But then have a look at this:

```
regex.test( $('#ytplayer').attr('src').toString() );
```

This will return `true` even though it is the exact same code, only with an added `toString()`. And yes, `.attr('src')` already returns a string! **Why is this?** I can reproduce this in Chrome and Firefox so it's most likely not a bug in a JS implementation.

(You can find a JsFiddle to try it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YHA6D/))

Comment: --I suppose, it only _looks_ like string, but actually it is something like `DOMPropertyValue`.-- No, I was wrong

Comment: Have you checked the `typeof` of both? Though yes, I'd certainly expect both to return `string`.

Comment: just checked http://api.jquery.com/attr/ , but they say it returns a String...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using the regex for testing do not use `g` flag

```
var regex = /(?:youtu\.be|youtube\.com|ytimg\.com|youtube-nocookie\.com).*(?:\/|\?v=|\&v=|\?video_id=|\&video_id=)([\w\-_]{11})[^\w\-_]?/i;
```

When you use the `g` flag the regex processor will remember the position of the last search and in the next search it will continue from there. if there was no match in the second search again the index will get resetted to 0;

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/72dxT/)

If you want further clarity look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/72dxT/3/) where the same search is repeated one after another where first one matches and second one fails

Comment: Yes, this is due to `g` flag.
`var regex = /(?:content)/ig;
[ regex.test( $('#content').attr('id') ),
  regex.test( $('#content').attr('id') ),
  regex.test( $('#content').attr('id') ),
  regex.test( $('#content').attr('id') ),
  regex.test( $('#content').attr('id') ) ]
[true, false, true, false, true]`

Comment: "Well, your regex is obviously wrong, check it again". I'm feeling rather stupid right now :(

Comment: @MartinThurau I had done the same mistake and asked a similar question in SO before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610251/why-pattern-testname-opposite-results-on-consecutive-calls